# flag option in the 10k tools review should act the same as "flag or disagree"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, flags, 10k-tools

When you are using the 10k tools to review flags, you get the following dialog:

> [image: Flag Dialog Shrunk]

If you click on the "Flag or Disagree" option, you get the following options:

> [image: Flag or Disagree Dialog]

If you expand the post out and click on flag:

> [image: Expanded Flagged Post]

You get a more limited set of options despite being in the review dialog:

> [image: Flag Dialog]

Since you are in the review dialog, clicking on that "flag" option should also give you the ability to disagree (select 'invalid flag').

Comment: How would you know there is a flag to say is invalid?

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Because he's looking at the post on the [flagged posts review page](http://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged)? _Every_ post there has been flagged, that's the whole point.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, ok, entering it from that point-of-view, but what if he entered the question flagging dialog from the question.  I thinking they may not want to track where you entered the 'flag from a post' dialog from.

Comment: @Lance, I am not asking for the flag dialog on the question to show that option, only that the flag dialog *in the flagged posts review* shows the option. And yes, I'm sure they are just using the question flag dialog options there right now, which is the source of the confusion, but it would be better for the flagged posts review dialog to show consistent flag dialogs regardless of which "flag" option you click.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Then they'll presumably decline this feature request, since that's pretty much exactly what it's asking for. (Note, however, that each post on the flag review page already has a button that _does_ bring up the dialog with the "disagree" option; it shouldn't be hard to write some JavaScript to intercept clicks on the "flag" link and redirect them to the button. In fact, I could probably whip up a user script to do that pretty easily...)

Comment: @Ilmari, if you can write a user-script to do it easily, it should be an equally easy fix on their side to do the same. Hence the request. I don't see why it would be declined (the request makes sense), though I can see it being very low priority (which is fine by me)

Answer (score 8):

I did some digging into the HTML, and here's what I found:

The "flag or disagree" buttons on the flagged post review page have the class attribute:

```html
class="flag-post-button show-invalid"
```

while the "flag" links on the posts themselves have the attribute:

```html
class="flag-post-link"
```

I had an idea, and decided to see what would happen if I used developer tools to change that to:

```html
class="flag-post-link show-invalid"
```

and what do you know?  **It works!**

> [image: Screenshot of flag dialog with "invalid flags" option shown]

The only remaining tricky bit, from a user script viewpoint, is that the expanded posts (including the flag links) are loaded using AJAX, so I'd have to hook into the loading process somehow to add the extra class name.  Presumably, this would be somewhat easier for the SE devs, since they actually have direct access to the code without having to hack it.

---

**Ps.** I did a bit more testing, and it turns out that this trick seems to work on *any* flag link, even in the normal question view, and even here on meta where I don't even have 10k yet(!).  I just gave this question an "invalid flags" flag to see if it would go through; looks like it did:

> [image: Screenshot of "invalid flags" flag]

My apologies for any potential confusion this may cause to the mod who ends up handling it. ;-)

---

**Update:** [Here's a working user script to implement this feature](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/223701), pending a proper fix from the devs.  The actual [code](http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/223701) is pretty simple:

```html
$('.mod-post-header').on(
    'mouseover',
    '.flag-post-link:not(.show-invalid)',
    function () {
        $(this).addClass('show-invalid');
    }
);
```

Instead of trying to hook into the AJAX code to attach the extra class name when the questions are expanded, this code simply uses jQuery's delegated even handling to insert it at the last moment when you move your mouse over the link to click it.  I *think* it should work on touchscreens too, but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: Awesome work. Thanks for the effort, and hopefully to make it easier for the devs to fix when they get around to it!

Comment: Hahaha yes. I came to this post and was like "what the hell is invalid?"

Comment: Well that's a massive bug you've found there Ilmari. Hope that gets fixed up all quick-like!

Comment: @jmac: [Fixed.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215250)

Answer (score 4):

I thought I'll implement this since I was already digging around in [that part of the woods](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215229/i-can-dispute-flags-without-10k-rep-and-so-can-you).

Will be with you in build `2013.1.7.1824` on meta and `2013.1.7.1278` on sites.

Comment: Nope, such thing does not exist. I just checked a random answer that got NAA flag and the answer's flag dialog has no "it has invalid flags" option. Am I missing something?

Comment: I just tried the same thing - flag an answer from the answer and there is not an "invalid flags option".

Comment: @chuex Are you trying to dispute a flag on the *question* from an answer or on the answer itself?

Comment: @anna My comment above refers to disputing a flag on an answer from the answer itself. The workflow is this: I see a flag in the 10k queue (e.g. not an answer), and then go to the answer to investigate. I conclude that the NAA flags are invalid. I click on the flag link from the answer, and don't see the "invalid flags" option. However, when I click the flag link from the 10k flags queue, I do see the "invalid flags" option. My understanding is that m0sa's fix makes the "invalid flags" option appear in both places.

Comment: @chuex Hmm. This might be a moot point soon since the 10k tools are going away altogether. Not 100% sure how this is supposed to work in that case.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yes with the 10k flag tools going away, I'm not sure how relevant this all is. I originally had flagged the question above to just get the [status-completed] tag removed. I believe jmac's issue is the same as what I describe (inconsistent flag options); m0sa's change, as I understand it, is supposed to fix this.

Comment: @chuex This is probably not worth revisiting either way with the queue going away. The gory details of how that's going to work are [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue). Thanks for keeping an eye out for things potentially regressing, though. It's appreciated. :)